# PoE standard compatibility

Tags: power-over-ethernet

I'm not sure if I understood all found info correctly, so I'm asking a question here.

I want to buy:

1. [Mikrotik hEX PoE (RB960PGS)](https://mikrotik.com/product/RB960PGS) as entry point of my home network

> ```
> PoE out                                   802.3af/at
> Max out per port output (input < 30 V)    1 A
> Max out per port output (input > 30 V)    450 mA
> Max total out (A)                         2 A
> ```

2. [Mikrotik Audience (RBD25G-5HPacQD2HPnD)](https://mikrotik.com/product/audience) as WiFi point

> ```
> PoE in                                    Passive PoE
> PoE in input Voltage                      24-57 V
> Number of DC inputs                       2 (DC jack, PoE-IN)
> DC jack input Voltage                     12-57 V
> Max power consumption                     27 W
> Max power consumption without attachments 27 W
> ```

I want to use router PoE to power WiFi point. If I understood correctly IEEE 802.3at should be enough to power this WiFi point. But I'm not sure about IEEE 802.3at and passive PoE compatibility. Maybe I need an adapter or something else.

Appreciate you help.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: @Maupin i think this question is more about PoE, than building home network.

Comment: It is also about off-topic devices. For a device to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support. Unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer that. You could edit the question to remove references to home networking and the off-topic devices, concentrating on the PoE, but the question will then likely get closed as a duplicate because we already have questions with answer about passive PoE and the PoE standards being incompatible.

Comment: See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=passive+poe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Passive PoE" is not (at all) compatible with IEEE PoE (802.3 af/at/bt). Usually, "passive" means using the 10/100 Mbit/s spare pairs for power. If you use different passive variants they may not work and things may release smoke.

IEEE PoE variants are carefully designed to only supply power to compatible devices. Without a device signature at the far end, a power source only puts a very small detection voltage on the wire, so nothing can break. Also, IEEE PoE may use the 10/100 signal pairs for "phantom" power, and it's compatible with Gigabit 1000BASE-T (or even 10GBASE-T).

So, you either pair a IEEE-compatible power source (PSE - switch or injector) with a likewise compatible device/splitter (PD), or you pair some "passive" injector/splitter devices that are compatible with each other. IEEE PoE is very plug-and-play, you only need to make sure that the PSE is able to handle the load - af/Type 1: <=12.9 W;  at/Type 2: <=25.5 W; bt/Type 3/4: <= 51/70 W.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I got it.